# crashplan peer-to-peer backup alternative

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I'm looking for a backup solution to replace Crashplan's peer-to-peer backup that has recently been discontinued.  I am looking for recommendations on a solution.  Here is my scenario:

I have several computers located at two different houses:

- houseA_server (Ubuntu 16.04)
- houseA_pc (Windows 10)
- houseB_server (Ubuntu 16.04)
- houseB_pc1 (Windows 10)
- houseB_pc2 (Windows 10)

I want to do local and remote backups. These are file backups, not whole disk images:

local backups (over local LAN):

- houseA_pc  --> houseA_server
- houseB_pc1 --> houseB_server
- houseB_pc2 --> houseB_server

remote backups (over internet):

- houseA_pc  --> houseB_server
- houseB_pc1 --> houseA_server
- houseB_pc2 --> houseA_server

Comment: did you meanwhile find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up implementing uses [BackupPC](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/index.html). Compared to Crashplan, I think the setup is a little more difficult. I used the [BackupPC docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/adferrand/backuppc) which makes setting up a little easier. Since BackupPC is open-source, I don't have to worry about the solution being discontinued. Another nice feature of this solution is that there is very limited client software required (on rsync or rsyncd).